# Use both operators in conditional render React

Tags: reactjs, conditional-rendering

I am trying to create a condition in order to render an error message in a React App.
This is my code  `{channel.length > 0 || sport.length > 0 && ref.current == true && <Error content={"Επιλέξτε φίλτρα"} />}`.
I am not getting back the Error component even though the conditions are met. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably need parentheses somewhere. But in cases like these with complex condition in template, it's better to create a dedicated function in the component with regular and readable `if` or `switch` statements.

Comment: Assigning your logic to a variable, e.g. `const showError = a || b && c` and then rendering with `{ showError && <Error />}` would generally be a cleaner approach and would avoid the issue you're seeing.

Comment: if `channel.length > 0` is true, then rest of the conditions would not be checked. Better to use the solution suggested in the comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put OR and AND operators in the order of their Precdence. AND (&&) has higher Precedence thatn OR(||). So you may like to put the OR (||) criterion in paranthesis and leave the rest like that. So it should be

```
{(channel.length > 0 || sport.length > 0) && ref.current == true && <Error content={"Επιλέξτε φίλτρα"} />}
```

In the above modification, `(channel.length > 0 || sport.length > 0)` has to be `true` for the entire block to return `true`.

You may like to use some `alert()`to trace the status.

Answer (score 1):

Use bracker `()` as `&&` operator has higher presedence than `||`

```
{((channel.length > 0 || sport.length > 0) && (ref.current == true) )&& <Error content={"Επιλέξτε φίλτρα"} />}
```